# Unspecified value parameters: for array in Scala

Tags: arrays, scala

```
 def rearrange(str: String) = {
    var indexes = Array[Int]()
    indexes = allIndexes(0, str, indexes)
    indexes foreach( println(_) )
  }

  def allIndexes(position: Int, str: String, tokens: Array[String], indexes: Array[Int]): Array[Int] ={
    tokens foreach( (e) => {
      var pos = str.indexOf(e, position)
      if (pos != -1){
        return allIndexes(pos, str, (indexes:+ pos))
      }else{
        return indexes
      }
    })
  }
```

[image]
What it complaining about? How to solve it?

Comment: You cannot use `foreach` in this case, its result type is `Unit` while you want to return `Array[Int]`.

Comment: What is a better alternative?

Comment: Maybe you could give an example in- and output for your `allIndexes` method ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32584203/480632

Comment: You need to give some more explanation on how these two questions are related.

Comment: I need to get messages of each person with their name, timestamp. So person's name would be delimiter for a string that combines all messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `allIndexes` requires 4 parameters, but you call the method only with 3 arguments. Thus, the compiler is complaining that the parameter `indexes` is unspecified.